# Навигация при повороте экрана

Tags: android, webview

Доброго времени суток.
Как осуществлять навигацию при повороте экрана?  Возможно не совсем ясно сказал - кнопку назад я обрабатываю, при повороте сохраняю текущий url, но возврат на предыдущею страницу при повороте экрана закономерно не работает. 
Нашел метод `copyBackForwardList` который возвращает `WebBackForwardList`, но как его присвоить `webview` при повороте не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняем состояние:

```
Bundle state = new Bundle();
webView.saveState(state);
```

Восстанавливаем:

```
webView.restoreState(state);
```

Comment: большое спасибо,я натупил  - начал мастерить свой велосипед по незнанию с load url и запилил левую проверку вместо canGoBack, когда нашел это в документации уже нагородил велосипедов и не убрал свою проверку (результат естественен ))) и начал городить такое .... пора спать словом )